# Cannot write <HTML> tags to text file in SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I've been working around a limitation put in place by a vendor and it is requiring me to write a SQL Server trigger that populates a text file that I then move to a mail pickup folder (it would be so much easier if the vendor would allow me to email directly form SQL.

With that said I can write to text files and move them just fine but what I cant seem to do is insert `<html>` tags into the text file.

When I try it just leaves that line out. Any help out there?

```
SET @from = 'FROM: no-reply@domainname.com' ;
set @to = 'TO: keith@domainname.com';
SET @subject = @subjecttext
SET @cmd = '(echo '+@from+' && echo '+@to+' && echo ' +@subject+') >//server02-2010/test/SprintTask.txt';
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, no_output;

--set @body = 'more text';
--SET @cmd = '(echo '+@body+') >>//server02-2010/test/SprintTask.txt';
--EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, no_output;

set @body = 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;' 
SET @cmd = '(echo '+@body+') >>//server02-2010/test/SprintTask.txt';
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, no_output;

Set @body = 'boundary="Attached"';
SET @cmd = '(echo '+@body+') >>//server02-2010/test/SprintTask.txt';
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, no_output;

Set @body = '--Attached' ;
SET @cmd = '(echo '+@body+') >>//server02-2010/test/SprintTask.txt';
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, no_output;

Set @body = 'Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8' ;
SET @cmd = '(echo '+@body+') >>//server02-2010/test/SprintTask.txt';
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, no_output;

Set @body = 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit' ;
SET @cmd = '(echo '+@body+') >>//server02-2010/test/SprintTask.txt';
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, no_output;

Set @body = '--Attached--'
SET @cmd = '(echo '+@body+') >>//server02-2010/test/SprintTask.txt';
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, no_output;

Set @body = '<b>' + 'THIS IS TEST TEXT';
SET @cmd = '(echo '+@body+') >>//server02-2010/test/SprintTask.txt';
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, no_output;
```

Comment: A trigger should be very **small and nimble** - it should most definitely *not* do any heavy lifting and extensive processing, like writing out to an external file..... you need to rethink your trigger strategy - this is a guaranteed recipe for horrible performance.....

Comment: Would you perhaps launch a stored procedure from the trigger to do the heavy lifting?

Comment: Keith, that would only change the location of the code being executed, not when it gets executed. You may want to look into a scheduled task that looks at created/modified timestamps compared to the log of when it last ran in order to move this to a less impactful scenario.

Comment: @Keith: that'll still be in the context of the transaction and thus doesn't help at all - see my answer

Answer (score 4):

A trigger should be very **small and nimble** since it executes in the context of the transaction that caused the trigger to fire.

It should most definitely *not* do any heavy lifting and extensive processing, like writing out to an external file...

I would recommend rethinking your trigger strategy - in your case, I would

- write a trigger that outputs the relevant information into a separate "PendingEmails" table (or something like this) - but nothing more
- create a separate program (could be a T-SQL stored procedure, or a front-end application written in C# or something) that would then consult that "PendingEmails" table on a scheduled basis, and if needed, would actually send out those e-mails you want to send out - in a separate process, not within the same database transaction

Otherwise, your trigger might end up taking a **long time** to complete, especially if it might need to wait for an external source to return with an acknowledgement - and this will happen **in the context** of your actual SQL statement - a sure fire way to kill off any performance your database might have had....

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you would like to write html tags using:

```
Set @body = '<b>' + 'THIS IS TEST TEXT';
SET @cmd = '(echo '+@body+') >>//server02-2010/test/SprintTask.txt';
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, no_output;
```

you need to understand that CMD.EXE echo ... is actually being performed. Since your @body contains < and > characters, CMD.EXE interpret this as:

1. redirect input from a file: <
2. redirect output to a file: >

To avoid this CMD.EXE's interpretation, you need to escape all html tag < and > characters, by placing a ^ (caret character) in front of the redirection characters like:

```
Set @body = '<b>' + 'THIS IS TEST TEXT';
SET @body = REPLACE(@body, '<', '^<'); -- escape <
SET @body = REPLACE(@body, '>', '^>'); -- escape >
SET @cmd = '(echo '+@body+') >>//server02-2010/test/SprintTask.txt'; -- here, of course, output redirection is needed
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, no_output;
```

Cheers, Paul